# Creating patterns in matlab / octave to show Moiré patterns

Tags: matlab, octave

How can I create radial images like this (see images below)

My goal is to control the number of radial arms, thinkness,  along with the angle they are created.  I'm trying to create patterns that will show me different Moiré patterns when overlapped and turned / animated in octave / matlab.

[image: radial 1]

[image: radial 2]

PS:  I'm using octave 3.8.1

I've tried the code here but it doesn't give me the fine tuning all of the following parameters, of radial arm amount, angle, and thickness.  Also the image package is needed which I'm trying to avoid.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/20287/moire_pattern.m

Comment: What have you tried? This question looks like a "pls give me the codez" question, and that is off-topic in  SO.

Comment: @Ander Biguri
I've tried the code here but it doesn't give me the fine tuning all of the following parameters, of radial arm amount, angle, and thickness.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/20287/moire_pattern.m

Also the image package is required

Comment: Then you didnt try. Copy-pasting a code is very far from actually triying. Get that code, modify it so the parameters you want are accepted, and if you have problems doing it then ask.

Comment: So if I didn't make it clear but I'm trying to avoid using the image package which is needed for this code...strange you asked me what I tried I found the code tried it and I had problems and this is bad...

Comment: Sorry Ricj, dont take this personally but thi is how SO policy works. We are not a code providing site. you need to try to code/modify your own functions and if you are stuck somewhere then we will help. Else there is no difference betwenn us and hiring a programer for doing the job for you, but the fact that you will not pay us.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it the two approaches which would be worth investigating first are equations and patches.

You could for instance generate a generic equation for an arm with parameters to control the rotation angle and the shape of the curve. You could then plot that at each of a given number of rotation angles, with varying linewidths (a plot property not an equation parameter). Your equation would probably not look pretty as you'd be best off specifying it parametrically (in terms of a third variable) or in polar coordinates, and then translating it to cartesian for the plot commands.

With patches you'd be computing the outline of the arm (as opposed to the centreline) and would probably find it convenient to generate the patch for one arm and then transform it for each rotation. This would be a one-liner with the appropriate rotational transform matrix, and the expression you use to generate the arm wouldn't need to be nearly so complex as it wouldn't need to handle the rotation. A quadratic might even do at a push.

Another advantage of patches is that, having generated an arm and rotated it around, you could also flip it and generate the figure with the opposite sense for very little extra code.